# Springfox 2.5.0 is not working with Spring 5.3.31

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

While upgrading the Spring version, **io.springfox : springfox-swagger2:2.5.0 & io.springfox : springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0** are not working with **spring 5.3.31**. Swagger UI is not loading properly, there is no such error or exception in the logs. Can you please have a look and help me with this.

I changed **io.springfox : springfox-swagger2** & **io.springfox : springfox-swagger-ui** to 3.0.0 but it is not working. I tried with 2.9.2 version as well but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Springfox was abandoned like 4 or 5 years ago. Use Springdocs instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with a lower version of springboot (2.4 ->2.7)
try working with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version> <!--- old version from 2021 -->
    </dependency>
```

also add this to your properties :

```
## Swagger-ui & Documentation
springdoc.packages-to-scan=de.xqueue.txe.api.controllers
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tryItOutEnabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.filter=false
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
springdoc.swagger-ui.validatorUrl=none
springdoc.swagger-ui.defaultModelRendering=model
springdoc.swagger-ui.docExpansion=full
```

Comment: My application is not in spring-boot but in spring. Can you please share configuration to be done for openapi-ui.

Comment: when working with openApi you dont need to add a java class for config .just add the dependency and the applicationp.properties config and you are good to go  .(http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs).  are you working with maven ?

Comment: Yes I am using maven but not spring boot so don't have application.properties. My application is in just spring . I hope now making sense.

Comment: Please help on my comment.