swagger not working after upgrading springfox swagger 2.9.2 to 3.0.0
Application : Spring 5.3.8.
before pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

after pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

**Added below property to Application.properties
**
springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3=false

Application starts with errors related to springfox swagger in tomcat
Caused
by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [$(springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3: true}] at org.springframework.beans propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor.setAsText(CustomBooleanEditor. java: 154) at org. springframework.beans. TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate. java: 429) at org-springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java: 402) at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary (TypeConverterDelegate.java:155) at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java: 73)
... 53 more

How can I resolve this error?
Is there an issue with the application.properties configuration or the dependency setup for Springfox 3.0.0?
Is the problem related to the use of Springfox 3.0.0 with Spring MVC 5.3.8?
Do I need to modify any additional configurations to upgrade from Springfox 2.9.2 to 3.0.0?
I have added below property in below property in application.properties still swagger URL does not load
springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3=false
removed @EnableSwagger2 and @configuration on the config class the error goes away but the swagger page doesn't load.

see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001672/springfox-2-5-0-is-not-working-with-spring-5-3-31?rq=2, besides you can use openapi3 instead.
